# i want feedback in email and that fedback data has to be stored in salesforce org

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, visual-workflow, custom-link

i have requirement like below.
 Send email through workflow > user receives email and filled some information like grades, agree , not agreed and bla bla.. >submit and these data has to be stored in my SFDC org.

any help on this .

thanks in advance .

Comment: Check out email services(https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Email_Services).. This should help you out..

Comment: @Mugambo that is not my requirement. :)

Comment: What object is going to kick off the workflow that sends the email?

Comment: Suppose i have an call center object when i resolved the issue the mail is fired to respective client and i want some input fields which our client should enter and after submit that data should be captured on SFDC org.

Comment: How are your users going to fill in this data? A link in the email to a VisualForce page that has a form on it? Simply replying to the email? It's hard to answer your question without this information.

Comment: @DanielBernsons i want that form is in email body itself. so that whenever client gets an email he can sumbit the form. because if external link is provided no one goes to that link and fill the survey.

Comment: @CloudArch I would strongly advise against that for many reasons. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428543/is-it-impractical-to-put-an-html-form-into-an-email) may be from 2009, but many of the reasons still stand today. So you're left with two choices, either asking your users to reply, or linking to a VisualForce page. If linking to a page, the controller can handle submitting to SF. If an email reply, then an Inbound Email Service as detailed by Mugambo and ajay is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

Email Services are one way to do this. Given the following example, you'd be able to send an email whose subject is the Account Id, body is the Account Name, and for storing create a field in your org and update it accordingly:

```
create a new Apex class "AccountUpdateEmailHandler" containing this code:

global class AccountUpdateEmailHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
  global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(
  Messaging.InboundEmail email,
  Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope)
  {
    String subject = email.subject;
    Pattern idPattern = Pattern.compile('001[A-Za-z0-9]{12}');
    Matcher matcher = idPattern.matcher(subject);
    if (!matcher.find()) System.assert(false, 'No Account Id in subject!');

    Account account = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :matcher.group(0)];
    account.Name = email.plainTextBody;
    update account;

    Messaging.InboundEmailresult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    result.message = 'Account Name is now ' + account.Name;
    return result;
  }
}
```

from Setup > Develop > Email Services, create one using the above class and Activate it.

and for any help visit this link:-

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com